# Require user input until is correct

Tags: python-3.x

What is the best way of repeatedly asking for the user for correct input?

For example I'd like to continue checking if the `a` value is an `int` or not and when it is finally say ok you picked number.

I'm stuck here:

```
    try:

      a = int(input())

    except:
       print("incorrect pick a number and try again")


#Somewhere here

print("Ok thanks you finally picked a number")
```

Answer (score 1):

The only exception you want to catch is the `ValueError` raised by `int` should it not be able to convert its argument to an integer. The `try` statement will be in a loop that you will explicitly break out of if you *don't* get an exception.

```
while True:
    response = input()
    try:
        a = int(response)
    except ValueError:
        print("incorrect pick a number and try again")
    else:
        print("Ok thanks you finally picked a number")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
a = None
while type(a) != int:
    try:
        a = int(input())
    except:
        print("incorrect pick a number and try again")

print("Ok thanks you finally picked a number")
```

Essentially:

- Create a variable with `NoneType` so when you first run the program it can access the while loop because the conditions meats.
- Loop until the type of that variable is not `int`.
- Request the user input and try to cast as integer, if it fails print an error and try again.
- When the input is of integer type it exit the loop and print the final message.

---

You can use `type()` or `isinstance()` to check, but as suggested by @chepner avoid the usage of `type` because it simply returns the type of an object whereas, `isinstance()` returns `true` if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo argument, or of a (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof.

To help you understand:

```
class foo:
    pass

class bar(foo):
    pass

isinstance(foo(), foo)  # returns True
type(foo()) == foo      # returns True
isinstance(bar(), foo)    # returns True
type(bar()) == foo        # returns False,and this probably won't be what you want.
```

In the case you want to use `isinstance()` the code will result as:

```
a = None

while not isinstance(a, int):
    try:
        a = int(input())
    except:
        print("incorrect pick a number and try again")

print("Ok thanks you finally picked a number")
```

---

As pointed out by @L3viathan you can also do:

```
a = None
while a is None:
    try:
        a = int(input())
    except:
        print("incorrect pick a number and try again")

print("Ok thanks you finally picked a number")
```

In this case you loop until `a` get a value, that will be done only if the exception is not thrown.

Comment: How would `type(a)` ever be anything other than `int` or `type(None)`? Why not do `while a is None:` instead in that case?

Comment: You almost never want to use `type(x) == y`; use `isinstance(x, y)` instead.

Comment: @chepner explain why please. As I know type() simply returns the type of an object whereas, isinstance(): returns true if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo argument, or of a (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof.

Comment: @CarloZanocco That's precisely why. You almost never care about the *exact* type, ignoring sub typing.

Comment: @chepner In this case how it could be a problem?

Comment: It's a bad habit to get into. Unless you have a *reason* for ignoring subtypes, don't do it.

Comment: @chepner Thanks, I have updated the question to also explain to the other

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    try:
        number=int(input("Enter a number: ")) 
    except:
        print("incorrect pick a number and try again")
    else:
        print("ok Thanks you finally picked  a number ")
        break
```

Comment: `number` is, by definition, an `int` if you reach the statement following the `try` statement.  You don't need `isinstance`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want/must mantain this code, i think the unique way is using a loop.

```
while True:
try:
    a = int(input('Insert a number:'))
    print ('Your number is {}'.format(a))
    break

except ValueError:
    print("incorrect pick a number and try again")
```

So if the user inserts an integer, the code prints number and break the loop else repeats the request.
I hope it's useful for you!